# Should I use arguments variable on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

What is the best way to use parameters on JavaScript?
- use arguments variable
- define a parameter

```
function greet() {
   console.log("Hello " + arguments[0]);
}

function greet(name) {
   console.log("Hello " + name);
}
```

Comment: For my suggestion second one `greet(name)`

Comment: use params or spread params but not argument as long as you can avoid it.
spread params : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Definitely use parameters.

Comment: It is a question that is mainly based on opinions so for me much better would be the second option

Comment: Why would you imagine that the first alternative is better?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on the usage. If you expect only to process one variable, then use the second one. If you don't know how many inputs you are processing, then you can use the first one.

```js
// processing single input
function greetPerson(name) {
   console.log("Hello " + name);
}

// processing multiple inputs that varies in number
function greetPeople(...people) {
   if (people.length > 1) {
      people.forEach(p => console.log("Hello " + p));
   } else {
      console.log("Hello " + people[0]);
   }
}
```

Also, it's better to use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) so that your parameters that you passed in to the function would be an `Array`. The built in `arguments` object is not an array and does not let you `Array` methods such as `forEach` or `map`, which can be a pain if you need to use them.